# How to correctly create Virtual Switch in Windows Server 2016 TP4 while installing Docker? (not boot2docker)

Tags: windows, powershell, docker

I have an installed **Windows Server 2016 Technical Preview 4** on VMware
Warkstation.
It has 2 GB RAM and 60 GB disk space.

I try to install **Windows Server Host** for **Docker** according to [official Microsoft instruction.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/deployment/deployment#windows-server-host)
[Instruction in general in the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZAjn.png)

I don't need a **Hyper-V Containers** technology so for this guide i don't have to make steps marked with a one asterisk '*'

So we have six steps that we have to do for install Windows Server Host and Docker:

1. **Install the Container Feature**
2. **Create Virtual Switch**
3. **Configure NAT**
4. **Configure MAC Address Spoofing**
5. **Install Container OS Images**
6. **Install Docker** **

I have a problem in step two: Creat Virtual Switch while typing next cmdlet in PowerShell:

```powershell
PS C:\> New-VMSwitch -Name "Virtual Switch" -SwitchType NAT -NATSubnetAddress 172.16.0.0/12
```

```
New-VMSwitch : Failed while adding virtual Ethernet switch connections.
Internal miniport create failed, name = '8A407781-1BF5-4BB0-8538-35CFF056C598', friendly name = 'vEthernet (Virtual Switch)', MAC = 'DYNAMIC': One or more arguments are invalid
(0x80070057).
At line:1 char:1
+ New-VMSwitch -Name "Virtual Switch" -SwitchType NAT -NATSubnetAddress ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-VMSwitch], VirtualizationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidParameter,Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.Commands.NewVMSwitch
```

What should I do in this case?

Comment: Is NAT a valid type for the SwitchType parameter in 2016?  The current documentation suggests that only internal or private.  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848455.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I was able to install docker using [Microsoft guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick_start/inplace_setup) about **auto-install** instead of using [manual guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/deployment/deployment#windows-server-host):

```
# Auto-install instruction.

PS C:\> powershell.exe
PS C:\> start-process powershell -Verb runas
PS C:\> wget -uri https://aka.ms/tp4/Install-ContainerHost -OutFile C:\Install-ContainerHost.ps1
PS C:\> C:\Install-ContainerHost.ps1 -HyperV

# Wrong!
```

But there is an error in the last line in key **-HyperV**.
We need to ingore it, so the last line looks like:

```
PS C:\> powershell.exe
PS C:\> start-process powershell -Verb runas
PS C:\> wget -uri https://aka.ms/tp4/Install-ContainerHost -OutFile C:\Install-ContainerHost.ps1
PS C:\> C:\Install-ContainerHost.ps1

# Currect!
```

Using correct instruction i was able to install docker.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error on a Nano Server the first time I ran:

```
PS C:\> New-VMSwitch -Name "Virtual Switch" -SwitchType NAT -NATSubnetAddress 172.16.0.0/12
```

SwitchType NAT is definitely correct because the command doesn't accept the NATSubnetAddress parameter for anything other then a NAT switchtype.
Run it a second time and then it worked on my Nano Server.

Comment: Did you use standard powershell or ISE? Somehow standard PS seem to work better.